# Django eb deploy error message

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While I was deploying Django Project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I received the following error. Everything works fine on localhost though.

```
Creating application version archive "app-160505_232739".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-c5493f58] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)..., level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'storages'. 
container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/03_python.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-c5493f58'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

`.ebextensions/03_python.config` file:

```
01_migrate:
    command: "python mooove_eb/manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
02_collectstatic:
    command: "python mooove_eb/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells that you are missing the `storages` module. From [AWS Elastic Beanstalk documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html):

> Elastic Beanstalk uses to requirements.txt to determine which package to install on the EC2 instances that run your application.

You need to create a file named `requirements.txt` and add the line

```
storages==<your storages version>
```

You can run `pip freeze` to see the version you are using on your development environment.

Comment: Agreed. Django is failing to bootstrap while trying to run the `migrate` command.

Comment: I had to run pip freeze > requirements.txt once with virtualenv on and once virtualenv off and combined them together. It worked!! Thanks for the help!